# Replace a word in a Word file with Excel VBA

Tags: excel, vba, ms-word

I am writing Excel VBA code to replace a word in Microsoft Word file with another word.

The code below has no effect.

```vb
Sub Combine_TrainingPlan_Test()

Dim objWord
Dim objDoc
Dim FileAddress As String

FileAddress = "C:\Users\Ali\Desktop\Test\T2.docx"

Set objWord = CreateObject("Word.Application")
objWord.Visible = True

Set objDoc = objWord.documents.Open(FileAddress)

With objDoc.Content.Find
    .ClearFormatting
    .Replacement.ClearFormatting
    .Text = "60028951"
    .Replacement.Text = "Goodbye"
    .Wrap = wdFindContinue
    .Execute Replace:=wdReplaceAll
End With

End Sub
```

I expect 60028951 to be replaced with Goodbye.

Comment: Have you tried stepping through the code to see what happens? Is the file actually being opened? BTW, is there a reason you are not writing this as a macro for Word?

Comment: Is `60028951` pat of a larger "word", or does it stand by itself?

Comment: FYI it looks like you're using late binding, but you're using Word constants like `wdFindContinue`, which Excel VBA doesn't know anything about without a VB project reference to the Word object library.   If you add `Option Explicit` do you get compile errors?

Answer (score 0):

Please try

```
Const wdFindContinue = 1
Const wdReplaceAll = 2
With objDoc.Content.Find
 .ClearFormatting
 .Replacement.ClearFormatting
 .Text = "60028951"
 .Replacement.Text = "Goodbye"
 .Wrap = wdFindContinue
 .Execute Replace:=wdReplaceAll
End With
```